# spring boot - embedded mongodb connection refused

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

In [this example spring boot project](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/demo-mongodb) I want to test the `MongoRepository` persistent layer as well as the `Service` class that uses the repository using an embedded mongodb. However, I get a `Connection refused: connect` error (`java.net.ConnectException`), see below for a more detailed stacktrace.

This is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=MongoConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class Test_TimezoneDao {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test_TimezoneDao.class);

    @Autowired private TimezoneDao dao;
    @Autowired private CounterService counterService;


    @Test
    public void test() 
    { /*...*/ }
}
```

using this config class

```
@Profile("test")
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.example.demomongodb"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages= {"com.example.demomongodb"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@AutoConfigureDataMongo
public class MongoConfig 
{ }
```

For spring to use the embedded mongodb I imported

```
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
       </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and configured in `application-test.properties`

```
spring.profiles.active=test
# tried both random port (port=0) and deterministic port
spring.data.mongodb.port=27019
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.database=mongo-example
```

The full error is this:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

Also tried with deleting mongo host and port from all application properties, same issue

**EDIT 2**

When I change the mongodb port to 0 as recommended in the [spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html) I get `java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine`. So it really tries port 0 and doesnt use a random port as described on the spring boot docs. This seems to not work at all..

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to create this bean as well in mongo config.

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="close")
public Mongo mongo() throws IOException {
    return new EmbeddedMongoBuilder()
        .version("2.4.5")
        .bindIp("127.0.0.1")
        .port(12345)
        .build();
}
```

[source](https://github.com/jirutka/embedmongo-spring)

Comment: no same problem (connection refused). Also the spring boot docs dont say anything about needing to manually create this bean
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html